# file object from indexeddb is killing my JS fetch request

Tags: javascript, php, file, synchronization, indexeddb

after researching the whole WWW, I am at the point of posting my question here. I develop a small web app to enable offline file storage like images with IndexedDB.

Works like a charme so far until I get to the point where my sync script (plain JS) grabs the file objects from my IndexedDB table:

File {fileId: 1, name: 'IMG_3574.jpg', lastModified: 1687457184884, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 22 2023 20:06:24 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit), webkitRelativePath: '', …}

The fileId parameter is a custom parameter that is created when inserting the File object into the IndexedDB table. I even tried cloning the File object to submit it in my formData object and also tried removing the fileId parameter from my File object - both without success.

```
//fileObj is the File object retrieved from IndexedDB 
formData.append("fileObj", fileObj);
formData.append("var1", val1);
        
        fetch('target.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: formData,
            referrerPolicy: 'origin',
            mode: 'cors',
            keepalive: keepItAlive
        })
```

The request then looks like this:
[image: screenshot from Chrome developer tools]

When I just remove the fileObj entry from my formData object, the request works just fine.

EDIT:
I also tried to add my fileObj to a DataTransfer object and add it to a html file input and take the file from there, but this also fails.

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById("my-temp-file-input");
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.items.add(fileObj );
fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
....
formData.append("fileObj", document.getElementById("my-temp-file-input")[0]);
```